# Why is pandas.dataframe.groupby faster when assigned to variable first?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, pandas, optimization

Can anyone please help understand why the following two ways of doing, what i thought was, otherwise the same thing with the **pandas.dataframe groupby method**, complete in such different times according to iPython's Magic %timeit?

```
%timeit somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn')['someBoolColumn'].count()
484 µs ± 9.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit grp = somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn')
grp['someBoolColumn'].count()
146 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

somedf has 7200 rows and 24 columns.

I cannot find,

1. why the two liner assigning the object to variable grp first is >3
   times faster, nor;
2. if this is just specific to the groupby method or
       something more general to pandas or even python, for example, about
       variable assigment.

Many thanks for any enlightenment as this would really help with many much larger dataframes i'd like to process, repeatedly with many different combinations of parameters.

Comment: Hey Jon, you've did [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18149782), you asked what you can do instead of editing the answer: These limits that you can't comment are there for a reason, [here you can read why these limits exists and what you can do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ipython's [`%timeit` docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit)  state:

> In cell mode, **the statement in the first line is used as setup code (executed
>     but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed**. The cell body has access to
>     any variables created in the setup code.

(my emphasis). `cell mode` is triggered by using the double-percent form of `%%timeit`.
There is also a blurb in the documentation that IPython prints when you type `%magic` at the IPython prompt:

> ```
> %%timeit x = numpy.random.randn((100, 100))
> numpy.linalg.svd(x)
> ```
>
> will time the execution of the numpy svd routine, running the assignment of x
>   as part of the setup phase, which is not timed.

---

Thus,

```
%%timeit grp = somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn')
grp['someBoolColumn'].count()
```

is timing `grp['someBoolColumn'].count()`, but not the assignment `grp = somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn')`.

---

**How to use `%%timeit` without a setup line**:

To use `%%timeit` to time both statements, simply leave the first line blank after `%%timeit`:

```
%%timeit 
grp = somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn')
grp['someBoolColumn'].count()
```

The cell is finished by typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. Confirmation: <br/>      `%timeit grp = somedf.groupby('someBoolColumn'); grp['someBoolColumn'].count()  
482 µs ± 7.69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: Thanks again @ubuntu for the subtle and important difference. Shame i cannot edit the question now to make it more useful for others, as it assumes %timeit was not the focus, which you have shown it is. If you could add anything such as 'How to use cell mode without a setup line, or some kind of dummy setup line' then i think that would be helpful to me and others, and very much appreciated. If not, then much appreciated already. Thanks.

Comment: Oh i can edit the question still. After the question i've added "A: iPython %timeit misuse." to hopefully make it more searchable and useful as clearly and quickly as possible. Please let me know if this is against StackOverflow etiquette, as this is the first question i've asked.

Comment: @JonB451: Thanks for thinking about how to make your question most useful for
others. Both versions of your question are good. Personally, I like questions
left in their "raw" form -- even if it include mistakes -- as long as the
question is clear. After all, searchers rarely ask questions in the absolute
best way, since doing so requires already knowing the answer. Leaving the
question in its mistaken form is good because it maximizes the chances of
helping others who have the same misconception.